# KRB_ERR, KDC_ERR_C_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN: Client not found in Kerberos database

Tags: kerberos

I can see the message using network capture tool Microsoft Message Analyzer. I can see the I receive Kerberos error "KDC_ERR_C_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN: Client not found in Kerberos database".

I can see all parts of the message, I have been searching online and tried a few things and did not work.

But in order to understand the problem, what does the "client" mean here?
 - Is it the Server / Computer that is requesting
 - Is it the Application that is requesting

The error is for KRB_TGS_REQ which means that its requesting for a token.

Would be great if anyone could help understand, which I believe can lead to a resolution.

Added more Details:

We have a SharePoint farm setup with SQL Reporting Services (SharePoint Integrated mode) and Excel Services. We have a datasource defined in Sharepoint which are used in SSRS Reports and Excel Reports. We use Windows Authentication from Sharepoint to SQL. When we test connection on Sharepoint datasource we get an error which says Cannot convert Windows token to Claims token. On opening the reports in SSRS we also receive error.

Strange part is that it works for some users which is why I'm not sure how to tackle this issue. If its SQL Server previlage issue, we have assigned sys admin role, this user also added as admin in SSRS. If AD or SPN issue it must not work for all users not for individual users.

I can see successful KRB_TGS_REQ for an admin user but fails for a normal user. No clue what to look for.

Kerberos Message :
KRB_TGS_ERROR, KDC_ERR_C_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN: Client not found in Kerberos database, Cname: **nothing**, Realm: SUB.DOMAIN.COM, Sname: **SP_SVC_ACT**

Does this mean that the delegation is not working?

Comment: The _client_ here would be referring to a missing SPN in your KDC.  _KRB_TGS_REQ_ will always fail when the SPN can't be found.   Missing SPNs generate this kind of message.  If you explain details regarding your architecture and what are you trying to do we can help you better.

Comment: We have a SharePoint farm setup with SQL Reporting Services and Excel Services. We have a datasource defined in Sharepoint which are used in SSRS Reports and Excel Reports.

Comment: Just an update not sure if it's really related the users that don't work belong to a different OU. They are not listed under AD\USERS instead is something like AD\DEPT\DIV\UserID